# Issue with running the sample pyramid program. Giving ImportError: No module named execptions error

Tags: python, pyramid

I am new to python and Pyramid.
I have installed pyramid today and i already have python 2.7.1 pre-installed on my mac machine.   I have installed pyramid with the [instructions mentioned in the official website](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/docs/pyramid_install.html). I have used the virtualenv with nositepackages as mentioned in the website and i installed pyramid in my `/users/sreekanth`  directory

After installing i tried my first sample program as mentioned  [in the docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/single_file_tasks/single_file_tasks.html).

When I try to run the program i am getting an error which is as below.

```
sreekanths-MacBook-Pro:tasks Sreekanth$ ../bin/python2.7 tasks.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 87, in <module>
    config.scan()
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 893, in scan
    scanner.scan(package, categories=categories, onerror=onerror)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/venusian-1.0a2-py2.7.egg/venusian/__init__.py", line 95, in scan
    invoke(name, ob)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/venusian-1.0a2-py2.7.egg/venusian/__init__.py", line 92, in invoke
    callback(self, name, ob)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/view.py", line 210, in callback
    config.add_view(view=ob, **settings)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 575, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*arg, **defaults)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/util.py", line 59, in wrapper
    result = wrapped(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 926, in add_view
    context = self.maybe_dotted(context)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 808, in maybe_dotted
    return self.name_resolver.maybe_resolve(dotted)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/path.py", line 318, in maybe_resolve
    return self._resolve(dotted, package)
  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/path.py", line 325, in _resolve
    return self._zope_dottedname_style(dotted, package)


  File "/Users/Sreekanth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/path.py", line 374, in _zope_dottedname_style
    __import__(used)
ImportError: No module named execptions
```

And also i am not able to import pyramid module from the python shell. Below is the error message i am getting.

```
sreekanths-MacBook-Pro:bin Sreekanth$ pwd
/Users/Sreekanth/env/bin
sreekanths-MacBook-Pro:bin Sreekanth$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyramid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyramid
```

Could someone kindly explain me what i am missing and how I can make this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error indicates you have a typo in your program. Most likely, you wrote

```
from pyramid.execptions import NotFound
```

instead of

```
from pyramid.exceptions import NotFound
#              ^^
```

And since you've installed pylons/pyramid into a virtualenv, you need to activate it first, with `source bin/activate` in the command line. That will set the correct python path, which you can check by examining `sys.path` in a python console.